# Having Trouble in Using bringToFront() Method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Hi friends iam new to android and in my project i got a requirement in which i need to show two layouts on same position and need to apply rotation animation whenever a button is pressed ,i achieved the same by creating the two layouts in same position and using Layout.bringToFront() method iam switching between them, but i don't know why in some cases it's animating properly but bringToFront() method doesn't carrying my layout to front

```
 public void bodyClicked()
 {
     System.out.println("Inside Body Clicked...");
     System.out.println("Enevelope boolean value... "+enevelopefocus);
     System.out.println("Body Boolean Value..."+bodyfocus);
     if(!bodyfocus)
        {
            bodyLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this, R.anim.rotate_right));
            fromToRootLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this,R.anim.rotate_left));
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            fromToRootLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this, R.anim.rotate_center_after_left));
                            bodyLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this, R.anim.rotate_right_center));
                            bodyLayout.bringToFront();
                            bodyLayout.invalidate();
                            bodyLayout.requestFocus();
                            bodyfocus=true;
                            enevelopefocus=false;
                            System.out.println("Body CLicked Completed...");
                            System.out.println("Enevelope boolean value... "+enevelopefocus);
                            System.out.println("Body Boolean Value..."+bodyfocus);
                            fromToRootLayout.invalidate();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 500);
            headerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
 }
 public void enevlopeCLicked()
 {
     System.out.println("Inside Enevelope Clicked...");
     System.out.println("Enevelope boolean value... "+enevelopefocus);
     System.out.println("Body Boolean Value..."+bodyfocus);
     headerLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fromBodyLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(fromAddressTExtView.getText().toString().length()>0)
        {
            fromAddressTExtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fromTopEditBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fromcontactpick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            fromTopEditBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fromcontactpick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fromAddressTExtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(toAddressTExtView.getText().toString().length()>0)
        {
            toAddressTExtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toBottomEditBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toContactPick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            toBottomEditBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toContactPick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toAddressTExtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if(!enevelopefocus)
        {
            fromToRootLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this, R.anim.rotate_left));
            bodyLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this,R.anim.rotate_right));
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            bodyLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this, R.anim.rotate_right_center));
                            fromToRootLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddJobNew.this, R.anim.rotate_center_after_left));
                            fromToRootLayout.bringToFront();
                            fromToRootLayout.invalidate();
                            fromToRootLayout.requestFocus();
                            enevelopefocus=true;
                            bodyfocus=false;
                            System.out.println("Enevelope CLicked Completed...");
                            System.out.println("Enevelope boolean value... "+enevelopefocus);
                            System.out.println("Body Boolean Value..."+bodyfocus);
                            bodyLayout.invalidate();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 500);
            headerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 }
 }
```

Here iam using two flags for body and enevelope whenever that particular button is clicked iam calling bringToFront() method here it's calling properly and flag value is changing properly but i don't know after coming to front its automatically going to background in some situations
please help me

Thanks

Comment: Please show the *relevant* code.  Please don't paste all of your code, just the bit where you're animating the layouts and using bringToFront()

Comment: I have Attached the Code Snippet @Simon

Comment: Having Problem when body is animating it's coming to front and  disappearing  automatically whenever i one again start animation it's behaving like its on top and moving to background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem now, mistake i did is some other part of code i have written the statement bodyLayout.setVisisbility(View.GONE) which effected my animation,